# Invalid argument error when using a script in neovim (which does work with classical vim)

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm using the plugin [vim-slime-cells](https://github.com/Klafyvel/vim-slime-cells) with Vim 8.1, which does work nicely.

However, when I try to open Neovim v0.4.3 it complains about this function in particular:

```
function! slime_cells#select_current_cell(include_header=0) abort
  let cell_delimiter = slime_cells#get_delimiter()
  if cell_delimiter == ""
      return
  endif

  let [line_ini, col_ini] = searchpos(cell_delimiter, 'bcnW')
  let line_end = search(cell_delimiter, 'nW')

  if !line_ini
    let line_ini = 1 
  elseif !a:include_header
    let line_ini = line_ini + 1 
    let col_ini = 1 
  end 
  " line before delimiter or bottom of file
  let line_end = line_end ? line_end - 1 : line("$")
  let col_end = strlen(getline(line_end))

  call setpos("'<", [0, line_ini, col_ini, 0]) 
  call setpos("'>", [0, line_end, col_end, 0]) 
  normal! gv
  let current_mode = mode()
  if current_mode != "V" 
    normal! V
  endif
endfunction
```

The error is exactly (sorry, in Spanish, but I think it can be understood OK):

```
Se ha detectado un error al procesar /home/navarro/.vim/bundle/vim-slime-cells/autoload/slime_cells.vim:
línea   13
E475: El argumento no es válido: include_header=0) abort
línea   16
E133: ":return" no está dentro de una función
línea   39
E193: ¡":endfunction" no está dentro de una función!
```

Is there anything in this function that makes it incompatible with Neovim? If so, how can I work around this?

Comment: `Neovim v0.4.3` <--- Doesn't it ring a bell for you? Just update.

Comment: Good point! I'm not familiar with the versioning scheme, I had just installed it using Ubuntu's standard repositories and I assumed it would be an OK version. Turns out it is a bit old. I have now manually installed v0.8.2 and it works nicely. Thanks!